# While loop is not restarting even when I set the variable to restart it

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to python and decided to try a text-based adventure as a starting project to learn the basics.

I have this while loop that restarts with the var valid_input if the user inputs the wrong word. It works, but I notice that even when it should restart already, it still reads the final else statement, giving an additional print that I only intend to show up when the user inputs the wrong action.

```
while valid_input == False:
    dec2 = input("Do you shout aloud or try to use something to light the place (shout/light)")
    if dec2 == "light":
        if "lighter" in inventory:
            print(">You use the lighter to light up the room")
            print(">You find yourself in a large cavernous structure")
            room_visible = 1
            valid_input = True
            break
        else:
            print(">You don't seem to have anything to light up the place.")
            valid_input = False
        if dec2 == "shout":
            print(">You shout at the top of your lungs and see what that does.")
            valid_input = True
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid action")
            valid_input = False
```

Update #1

I fixed up the code and tried to properly indent it since that was the recommendation. It made sense to me although it still printed out the "Invalid Action" message regardless.

I decided to randomly put a valid_input = True in the else statement and it seemed to work. This is currently the code that works, although I don't understand why it worked. Hoping someone could explain!

```
while valid_input == False:
    dec2 = input("Do you shout aloud or try to use something to light the place (shout/light)")
    if dec2 == "light":
        if "lighter" in inventory:
            print(">You use the lighter to light up the room")
            print(">You find yourself in a large cavernous structure")
            room_visible = 1
            valid_input = True
            break
        else:
            valid_input = True
            print(">You don't seem to have anything to light up the place.")
            valid_input = False
    elif dec2 == "shout":
        print(">You shout at the top of your lungs and see what that does.")
        valid_input = True
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid action")
        valid_input = False
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation.  As written, we can't tell what parts are indented underneath the while loop.

Comment: Also, it's not clear what you mean when you say "restart" the loop.  There is only one loop here, and when it's done, it's done; there is no way for it to "restart".  Is there some outer loop or other containing structure that you haven't shown us?

Comment: Looks like your indentation is messed up maybe? the `if dec2 == "shout"` looks like it should be at the same indentation level as the `if dec2 == "lighter"` and should be an `elif`, would that be fair to say?

Comment: The final `if dec2 == "shout"` statement is _inside_ the `if dec2 == "light"` branch, so there's no way it can ever be true, and so the `else` branch always executes.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yeah that was actually the indentation of the code and you guys pointed out that it was wrong so I fixed it up! That didn't really fix the issue, but will still keep in mind when formatting my code. :)

Comment: I feel strange because the `valid_input = True` you added should do nothing. I interested what input you use so it still print out invalid action with Kartik's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The final `if dec2=="shout" ... else ...` are inside the code block `if dec2=="light"`.
If the user inputs "light", this if-else combo will be executed. Since `dec2` is `light`, it is not `shout` and hence, the interpreter enters the `else` block and prints `"Invalid action"`.

You probably want the following code

```
while valid_input == False:
    dec2 = input("Do you shout aloud or try to use something to light the place (shout/light)")
    if dec2 == "light":
        if "lighter" in inventory:
            print(">You use the lighter to light up the room")
            print(">You find yourself in a large cavernous structure")
            room_visible = 1
            valid_input = True
            break
        else:
            print(">You don't seem to have anything to light up the place.")
            valid_input = False
    elif dec2 == "shout":
        print(">You shout at the top of your lungs and see what that does.")
        valid_input = True
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid action")
        valid_input = False
```

Comment: Hey thanks for that. The logic is sound and makes sense to me although when I tried it out it still prints out the "Invalid Action" message.  What I randomly tried to to was put valid_input = True before the else statement and it seemed to work although I still don't understand why.